# Django - Database design

Tags: python, django, database

I have the following database so far:

```
Person model
Student model inherits from Person, no added functionality
Lecturer model same as Student
Course model 
     leader = ForeignKey to Lecturer (1 Lecturer can have many courses)
     students = ManytoMany with Student (Many students can take many courses)
Card model
     student = OneToOne with student (1 card per 1 student).
Event model
     course = ForeignKey to Course (One course can have many events)
```

Now my question is; I want to mark students present in an event based on the following criteria. On creation of Event, marked students need to be empty. Later I will create a view that will register a Card ID. The Card model has a 1-1 relationship with student. Student is many-many with Course. Course is a FK to Event.

- They need to be part of the same course that the Event is connected to.
- The marked present students need to be visible inside the model later on.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason that `Card` isn't just a column in the `Student` model? Why the one-to-one relationship?

Comment: @JonahBishop My reasoning was that when cards get lost, they can be replaced, but I suppose that can be done as a field as well. Second reason was that in the future I wanted to extend the card to be connected to lecturers for authentication so wanted to use a separate model

Comment: Ah, I see. It does make some sense to have a separate table (you could then mark the cards as void or something if they were lost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I might use a dedicated Attendance table (something like the following):

```
class Attendance(Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student')
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
    present = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

You could swap out the student field for a Card instead, if that's what you desire (but since it's a one-to-one, it doesn't really matter). The default value for the `present` field could also be swapped, depending on how you want to treat entries in this table.